# Angular scroll to an element from inside the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to scroll to an element from inside the controller.

Using the `du-smooth-scroll` and the `href="#invoice-wrapper"` works fine on buttons and other elements inside the angular html page.

```
<button du-smooth-scroll href="#invoice-wrapper"> 

<!--Invoice Form-->
<div id="invoice-wrapper"></div>
```

Is there a way to activate the same thing from inside the controller?

```
vm.scrollTo = (element) => {
    du-smooth-scroll(element) 
}
```

Or something like that?  Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `$scope.$broadcast` and catch the event from the directive though this will only work if `du-smooth-scroll` is present in your view.

```
// in your controller
vm.scrollTo = (element) => {
  $scope.$broadcast("du-smooth-scroll", element);
};

// in your directive
$scope.$on("du-smooth-scroll", function (element) {
  // call your function that does that scroll
});
```

I you want another way I suggest creating a global `scrollTo` function which can be used in both your directive and controller or anywhere

```
$rootScope.scrollTo = function (element) {
  // do the scroll thing
};
```

then just simply call `$rootScope.scrollTo(element)` in your controller and your directive.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in [$anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) like so:

```
$anchorScroll('invoice-wrapper');
```